# How best to notify clients of changes in data via API

Tags: api

I have an internal API for my company that contains a large amount of factual data (80MM records as of right now). I have four clients that connect to me on a regular basis. The main API call adds a new item to the database, verifies its authenticity, and then returns structured, analyzed data based on the item submitted.

Over time, as we identify more data to be associated with an item, I need to be able to let my clients know that records have changed.

Right now I have a `/recent` endpoint, which returns all of the records that have changed since `$timestamp`. This is fine for small data sets, but given the large number of transactions, one could easily wind up with a /recent dataset of over a million items, especially if there's a large data import.

Another idea I had was to use web hooks to push data to the clients, but then the problem becomes pushing too much data. My clients don't necessarily need updates for every single item that changed -- maybe they only need ones they've already submitted.

The question is less about code and more about design patterns or code strategies:

**What are some optimal strategies for notifying my clients of updated records without flooding my clients with unnecessary requests or providing millions of records on a poll?**

Answer (score 0):

I've used 3rd party APIs (such as Amazon) that paginate large requests. If the data set exceeds the page limit the client needs to make another a request for the next page. This would be in combination with the /recent endpoint.

The actual implementation would be something like

```
{
  requestId: "foobar",
  page: 0,
  pages: 10,
  data: {
    ...
  }
}
```

The client makes the request and gets the first page of data, then sends to an endpoint the requstId and the page number. Somehow you'd want to persist a reference to what data corresponds to a requestId.